# Frama-c, non-deterministic float values

Tags: c, frama-c

As example I use the following function:

```
float nondet_float(){
  float x;
  return x;
}

int main(){
  float x = nondet_float();
  if(isnan(x)){
    some_error();
  }
}
```

I wonder how I have to use frama-c, to simulate non-deterministic floats.

Want I want is, that the variable x, is considered to be any possible float value, including -inf, +inf and NaN.

I'd like to get the result that some_error() is reachable, if x is NaN.

So my question is:

how do I simulate non-deterministic floats?
how do I test for reachability of certain function calls?

Comment: the function: `nondet_float()` is returning the contents of an uninitialized local variable.  The result is undefined behavior.  Suggest re-thinking, perhaps by using `srand()` and `rand()` to get a float value.

Answer (score 1):

Frama-C is a collection of plugin, with different level of support for infinite/NaN floating-point values. I believe WP supports NaN and infinites; but this probably depend on the numeric model you choose (option `-wp-model`).

For the abstract interpretation plugin (EVA, formerly Value), NaN and infinites are not supported for the moment. The analyzer supposes (and proves) that all floating-point values are finite. Support for non-finite ones will be added in Frama-C Sulfur.

Also, your `nondet_float` function is invalid in any case. Returning uninitialized values is forbidden by the C standard, and this function will be flagged as incorrect by e.g. EVA. Instead, you should use a function without a body, with the clause `assigns \result \from \nothing` as its specification.

Comment: Can you make an example for that? I don't quite understand how you mean it.

Comment: For which part of the answer. Also, which plugin do you plan on using?

Comment: An example for: "instead, you should use a function without a body, with the clause assigns \result \from \nothing as its specification."


Optimally I would need a plugin with which I can prove/disprove the reachability of a specifiy piece of code. For my example i'd like to find out if the call of some_error() is reachable.

Which WP and Abstract Interpretation could both do.
And also Aorai, which after my understanding performs Trace Abstraction.

As I need support for NAN/INF, I can't use the Abstract Interpretation I guess, so I have to use the WP/Aorai plugin.